# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Asp.Net core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I was following [a tutorial](https://youtu.be/IGnazp7hQ6E) about paginate. it all worked, but if I add some sorting & filtering from my old code, it doesn't work. and the error says

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This is my controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return View(await GetStudentList(1));
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int currentPageIndex)
{
    return View(await GetStudentList(currentPageIndex));
}

// GET: Students

public IActionResult IndexProses(string sortOrder, StudentVM model)
{
    ViewData["CurrentSort"] = sortOrder;
    ViewData["NameSortParm"] = sortOrder == "name" ? "name_desc" : "name";
    ViewData["DateSortParm"] = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";
    ViewData["FirstSortParm"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "first_desc" : "";

    ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = model.FirstMidName;
    ViewData["CurrentFilter2"] = model.LastName;
    ViewData["CurrentFilter3"] = model.EnrollmentDateFrom;
    ViewData["CurrentFilter3"] = model.EnrollmentDateUntil;

    var students = from s in _context.Students
                   select s;

    // sorting // 
    students = sortOrder switch
    {
        "name" => students.OrderBy(s => s.LastName),// asc last name
        "name_desc" => students.OrderByDescending(s => s.LastName),//desc last name
        "first_desc" => students.OrderByDescending(s => s.FirstMidName),// desc first name
        "Date" => students.OrderBy(s => s.EnrollmentDate),// asc date
        "date_desc" => students.OrderByDescending(s => s.EnrollmentDate),// desc date
        _ => students.OrderBy(s => s.FirstMidName),// asc first name
    };

    // filtering
    if (model.EnrollmentDateFrom != null && model.EnrollmentDateUntil != null)
    {
        students = students.Where(s => s.EnrollmentDate >= model.EnrollmentDateFrom && s.EnrollmentDate <= model.EnrollmentDateUntil);
    }
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.LastName))
    {
        students = students.Where(s => s.LastName.Contains(model.LastName));
    }
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.FirstMidName))
    {
        students = students.Where(s => s.FirstMidName.Contains(model.FirstMidName));
    }
    return View("Index", model);
} 

private async Task<StudentVM> GetStudentList(int currentPage)
{
    int maxRowsPerPage = 5;
    StudentVM model = new StudentVM();
    model.StundentList = await (from s in _context.Students select s)
        .Skip((currentPage - 1) * maxRowsPerPage)
        .Take(maxRowsPerPage).ToListAsync();

    double pageCount = (double)((decimal)_context.Students.Count() / Convert.ToDecimal(maxRowsPerPage));

    model.pageCount = (int)Math.Ceiling(pageCount);
    model.currentPageIndex = currentPage;
    return model;
}
```

my assumption is because filtering & sorting is using Get method, but paging is using Post method. but i dont know how to fix it:(, here's the [error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l95I0.png). The Index.cshtml file:

```
    @model ContosoUniversity.Models.SchoolViewModels.StudentVM


@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Students";
    //List<Student> students = ViewBag.students; 
}

<style>
    table{
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .table a{
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    /*.opsi a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
    }*/
    
    h2{
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .tbl{
        display: flex;
        gap: 1rem;
    }

    .box{
        display: flex;
        gap: 1rem;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
</style>
<h2>Contoso University - Students</h2>

<form asp-action="IndexProses" asp-antiforgery="false" method="get">
    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <h4>Search By</h4>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="search">
                <label asp-for="FirstMidName"></label>
                <input name="FirstMidName" type="text" value="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]"/>
                <br />
                <span asp-validation-for="FirstMidName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            
            <div class="search">
                <label asp-for="LastName"></label>
                <input name="LastName" type="text" value="@ViewData["CurrentFilter2"]"/>
                <br />
                <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="search">
                <label asp-for="EnrollmentDateFrom"></label>
                <input name="EnrollmentDateFrom" type="date" value="@ViewData["CurrentFilter3"]"/>
                <br />
                <span asp-validation-for="EnrollmentDateFrom" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="search">
                <label asp-for="EnrollmentDateUntil"></label>
                <input name="EnrollmentDateUntil" type="date" value="@ViewData["CurrentFilter4"]"/>
                <br />
                <span asp-validation-for="EnrollmentDateUntil" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>


<div class="tbl">
    <a asp-action="Create" class="btn btn-primary">Create New [+]</a>
    <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-info text-white">Back to List</a>
</div>

<form asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Students" method="post">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr class="table-light">
                <th class="table-light">
                    @Html.ActionLink("First Name", "IndexProses", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.FirstSortParm, FirstMidName = Model.FirstMidName, LastName = Model.LastName, EnrollmentDateFrom = Model.EnrollmentDateFrom, EnrollmentDateUntil = Model.EnrollmentDateUntil })
                </th>
                <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Last Name", "IndexProses", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, FirstMidName = Model.FirstMidName, LastName = Model.LastName, EnrollmentDateFrom = Model.EnrollmentDateFrom, EnrollmentDateUntil = Model.EnrollmentDateUntil })
                </th>
                <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Enrollment Date", "IndexProses", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.DateSortParm, FirstMidName = Model.FirstMidName, LastName = Model.LastName, EnrollmentDateFrom = Model.EnrollmentDateFrom, EnrollmentDateUntil = Model.EnrollmentDateUntil })
                </th>
                <th>Opsi</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="opsi">
            @foreach (var item in Model.StundentList)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstMidName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EnrollmentDate)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a class="btn btn-warning text-white" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Edit</a> |
                        <a class="btn btn-info text-white" asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Details</a> |
                        <a class="btn btn-danger" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <ul class="pagination">
        @for(int i=1; i<=Model.pageCount; i++)
        {
            <li class="page-item">
                @if(i != Model.currentPageIndex)
                {
                    <a class="page-link" href="javascript: PagerClick(@i);">@i</a>
                }
                else
                {
                    <a class="page-link">@i</a>
                }
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
    <input type="hidden" id="hfCurrentPageIndex" name="currentPageIndex"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function PagerClick(index)
    {
        document.getElementById("hfCurrentPageIndex").value=index;
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }
</script>
```

here's the ViewModel

```
 public class StudentVM : IValidatableObject
    {
        public int currentPageIndex { get; set; }
        public int pageCount { get; set; }
        public List<Student> StundentList { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Last Name :")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "First Name :")]
        public string FirstMidName { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "Date From :")]
        public DateTime? EnrollmentDateFrom { get; set; } // ? (NULLABLE)

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "Until :")]
        public DateTime? EnrollmentDateUntil { get; set; } // ? (NULLABLE)

        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (FirstMidName == null)
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("input first name!", new[] { "FirstMidName" });
                //Memberi validation jika sebuah kolom pencarian tidak diisi!
            }
            
            if (LastName == null)
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("input last name!", new[] { "LastName" });
                //Memberi validation jika sebuah kolom pencarian tidak diisi!
            }

            if (EnrollmentDateFrom == null)
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("input date from!", new[] { "EnrollmentDateFrom" });
                //Memberi validation ke variable yang dituju!
            }
            if (EnrollmentDateUntil == null)
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("input date until!", new[] { "EnrollmentDateUntil" });
                //Memberi validation ke variable yang dituju!
            }
        }
    }
```

For the filtering & sorting tutorial, I am following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @YongShun i dont really know which one can solved my problem, sorry im new in c# & asp.net

Comment: From your code, you didn't initialize value to `model.StundentList`. You can place a breakpoint in this line: `return View("Index", model);` to check the mentioned value.

Comment: @YongShun The line just above it initializes the class `model` so I don't think so this is the issue.

Comment: A good start would be to tell where this exception occurs and show the stack trace. Also, do yourself a favor and use correct spelling for English words in code, like StudentsList (or preferably just "Students"), IndexProcess. It will help you in searches through your code later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to instantiated model.StundentList and fill it first:

```
public IActionResult IndexProses(string sortOrder, StudentVM model)
{
    ......
    model.StundentList = new List<Student>();
    foreach (var student in students)
    {
        model.StundentList.Add(student);
    }
    return View("Index", model);
}
```

In addition, your code seems to have logic problems, perhaps because you haven't finished it yet.

I suggest you use the method in [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-6.0#add-paging-to-students-index) for paging.

**Update:**

Because you submit the forms[0] when you click on the page number, the post method of Index is not called.

Change

```
document.forms[0].submit();
```

to

```
document.forms[1].submit();
```

This allows you to call the post method of Index.

Comment: thank you! it worked, but after i do filtering/sorting, the pagination is not working, its because the return view are supposed to like this `return View("Index", await GetStudentList(1));` is there any way to add `model` to the return? because if i did this `return View("Index", model, await GetStudentList(1));` it didn'work.

Comment: I update my answer, you can have a try. @zeinmu

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `Model.StudentList` is null. It's a good idea to check for null before inserting it into the loop.

Comment: the model is not null. the data is show up. but when i click paging/search/sorting button, it causes the error